# How can I read the csv file in pandas which is separated with ";"?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, dataset

I started working with pandas in python 3.4 for couple of days. I chose to work on [Book-Crossing data set](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~cziegler/BX/).
The book information table is like this:
[image: Books information]
The Book rating table is like this:
[image]
I want to grab the "ISBN","Book-title" from the book information table and merge it with the book-rating table in which both match the "ISBN" and after that write the results in another csv file.
I used the code below:

```
udata = pd.read_csv('1', names = ('User_ID', 'ISBN', 'Book-Rating'), encoding="ISO-8859-1", sep=';', usecols=[0,1,2])
uitem = pd.read_csv('2', names = ('ISBN', 'Book-Title'), encoding="ISO-8859-1", sep=';', usecols=[0,1])
ratings = pd.merge(udata, uitem, on='ISBN')
ratings.to_csv('ratings.csv', index=False)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\masoud\Desktop\Dataset\data2\a.py", line 2, in <module>
udata = pd.read_csv('2.csv', names = ('User_ID', 'ISBN', 'Book-Rating'),encoding="ISO-8859-1", sep=';', usecols=[0,1,2])
File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.6\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 491, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.6\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 278, in _read
return parser.read()
File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.6\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 740, in read
ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.6\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1187, in read
data = self._reader.read(nrows)
File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 758, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:7919)
File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 780, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:8175)
File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 833, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:8868)
File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 820, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:8736)
File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1732, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:22105)
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8   fields in line 6452, saw 9
```

I was wondering if anybody could fix the error?

Comment: OK. I did as you asked.

Comment: It says that in line number 6452, there is an extra presence of your sep char `";"` which it tried to split onto multiple columns that wasn't available. Maybe try `error_bad_lines=False`, but this would skip the erroneous lines while outputting the line numbers skipped. Another option would be to process the correct & incorrect parsings by reading them separately after identifying the bogus ones.

Answer (score 0):

In the first and second row, change `sep` to `;`.

```
sep=';'
```

Comment: I edited the question and changed the sep = ',' to sep = ';'.